# Link to own match's exact path in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have several nested routes using `react-router-dom` version 4.2.2, and I'd  to offer a "back" button on a root route. For example, if my hierarchy is

- `/base/:id`: An index page representing a resource, linking to and conditionally rendering the inner activities

  - `/base/:id/some-inner-activity`: A page representing one inner activity
  - `/base/:id/some-other-inner-activity`: A page representing another inner activity

I'd like to be able to offer a link rendered by the base component that just brings you back to `/base/:id`, so all activities can have a shared "back" or "up" behavior. I can do this with `/base/${match.params.id}`, but that means I have to hard-code `/base/` within the base component, so if I were to change the route that it's on, I would have a bunch of broken links.

I'd like to be able to use the `match.path` along with `match.params`, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that's sanctioned by React Router, and I definitely don't want to implement this myself.

I've put together a code sandbox demonstrating my preferred behavior, but you'll notice within the `Base` component I still have to hard-code the `/base/` string to generate the back button URL.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/n5r30r2qmm

Answer (score 0):

React Router offers [generatePath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/generatePath), which can be called as `generatePath(match.path, match.params)`.

As a side note, this won't work well with TypeScript, so you may have to do `generatePath(match.path, match.params as {[paramName: string]: string;})` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try referencing props.params.whateveridyouwant

Another way would be to push the match.params to the redux store so then you can access it wherever you want in your app.

Hope this helps! Or steers you in the right direction!